# Strategy entry point on Tradingview not consistent with what I see on indicators

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I created a simple strategy that uses both stochastic and stochastic RSI (in both cases k needs to crossover d).

Fact is, the strategy does not work as it should. For example, here, it does not enter the trade:

[image]

The image is referring to this symbol: **Gold, TVC. Timeframe 1h**

**Of course, I have checked that the parameters are the same in the indicators and the strategy**. Also the script I use to calculate the indicators is copied directly from the script of the indicators themselves, so the results SHOULD be identical.

[image]

Here is the code of the strategy:

What is happening here?

```
//@version=4
strategy("Stochastic RSI", overlay=true)


/// Stochastic RSI
smoothK = input(5, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input(8, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
rsi1 = rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)

/// Stochastic
periodK = input(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothKSto = input(7, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)
stok = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothKSto)
stod = sma(k, periodD)

atr = atr(5)

/// strategy
long_entry = crossover(k,d) and crossover(stok,stod)

profitAmount = strategy.position_avg_price + atr * 1.5
profit = close > profitAmount
stoplossAmount = strategy.position_avg_price - atr * 1.5
stoploss = close < stoplossAmount

// Enter long trade
if (long_entry)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// Exit long trade
if (profit or stoploss)
    strategy.close("Long")
```

Comment: What is the ticker id and timeframe?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the result of the `k` from the Stochastic RSI calculations in your Stochastic calculation. Those are not the same. You should use the `k` from Stochastic in your Stochastic `d` calculation.

```
stok = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothKSto)
stod = sma(stok, periodD)  // Use stok here
```